# Sticky Code injection blocks

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using Anya theme on squarespace with a Caspio backend. I've injected code in two separate blocks. One for a search form and the other for the results form.

I've been trying to make the search form a sticky at the top of the screen as the user scrolls down the page. I've identified the block id and tried various ways to make it sticky using the same code as sticky navigation. To no avail. Is it possible to make any Block floating during scroll?

So far I have this and variations I've tried of it. I've put it in the custom css.

```
#block-yui_3_17_2_5_1447688437263_5840 {
    .primary-nav {
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 99999;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using SASS or just plain CSS?